# Instance variable being set to null no matter what

Tags: java, object

So I'm trying to create an object "Cat" where it has a name, weight, and mood. After assigning the Cat values to these variables, it only prints the name and weight, but not the mood. It'll say something like: "Name: Cat, Weight: 10lbs, Mood: null", no matter if the mood is valid or not.

I thought this might be a problem with the mutators but I couldn't find anything that would fix it. To take it a step further, the class's attribute that inherits this "Cat" class also has this problem, but its new attribute doesn't, so it'd look like "Name: Cat, Weight: 10lbs, Mood: null, Type: short hair". Why is this happening?

```
public class Cat extends Animal{

//Attributes
private String mood;

//Constructors
public Cat()
{
    super();
    this.mood = "no mood yet";
}
public Cat(String aName, double aWeight, String aMood)
{
    super(aName, aWeight);
    this.setMood(aMood);
}

//Accessors
public String getMood()
{
    return this.mood;
}

//Mutators
public void setMood(String aMood)
{
    if(aMood.equalsIgnoreCase("sleepy") || aMood.equalsIgnoreCase("playful") || aMood.equalsIgnoreCase("hungry"))
    {
        this.mood = aMood;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid mood.");
    }
}

//Other Methods
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " | Mood: " + this.mood;
}


public class Animal {

//Attributes
private String name;
private double weight;

//Constructors
public Animal()
{
    this.name = "no name yet";
    this.weight = 0.0;
}
public Animal(String aName, double aWeight)
{
    this.setName(aName);
    this.setWeight(aWeight);
}

//Accessors
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}
public double getWeight()
{
    return this.weight;
}

//Mutators
public void setName(String aName)
{
    this.name = aName;
}
public void setWeight(double aWeight)
{
    if (aWeight > 0.0)
    {
        this.weight = aWeight;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid weight.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The information provided here is not enough to find the root cause of the problem. Please show the `Animal` class code and code that creates a `Cat` instance etc...

Comment: Can you please post the Super class too to understand the problem.

Comment: updated, sorry.

Comment: It would also help if you provided the code that is instantiating or setting the "mood" from outside the Cat class.

Comment: You're missing the Animal class's toString() method, but I can guess what it looks like.  This should work unless an invalid "mood" is passed in.

Comment: Try this: run your test and pay attention to the output.  Specifically look for the message "I don't pay attention" which you mistyped as "Invalid mood."